# Linux Kernel Boot: Failed to execute /init (error -2)

Tags: linux-kernel, busybox

I'm trying to create a minimal linux distro using the tutorial "Build a minimal Linux with only Busybox in 1 hour" of "Write your own Operating System
" all worked bue when I boot it, it give to me:

```
[    0.187524] Run /init as init process
[    0.187624] Failed to execute /init (error -2)
[    0.187674] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    0.187707] Run /etc/init as init process
[    0.187753] Run /bin/init as init process
[    0.187807] Run /bin/sh as init process
[    0.187872] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
[    0.187973] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.18.9 #1
[    0.188032] Call trace:
[    0.188044]  dump_backtrace.part.0+0xcc/0xe0
[    0.188103]  show_stack+0x18/0x6c
[    0.188117]  dump_stack_lvl+0x68/0x84
[    0.188167]  dump_stack+0x18/0x34
[    0.188195]  panic+0x168/0x328
[    0.188215]  kernel_init+0x12c/0x13c
[    0.188262]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[    0.188279] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[    0.188340] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    0.188363] CPU features: 0x000,0000140a,59a49dc8
[    0.188409] Memory Limit: none
[    0.188426] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. ]---
```

init file:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t devtmpfs udev /dev
sysctl -w kernel.printk="2 4 1 7"
/bin/sh
```

Comment: `[    0.187872] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.`

Comment: well, did you do what your error log asks you to do?

Comment: how can I in QEMU?

Answer (score 0):

1. set BINFMT_SCRIPT to allow Kernel run scripts... actually allow to run not-binary-INIT like yours.
   After that Kernel will rise "error 8" instead "error 2" because Kernel should allow to run binary-ELF (/bin/sh for example).
2. So now you need to set BINFMT_ELF also.

Comment: already resolved

Comment: @Paolo would you care to share how you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the next person who runs into this error:
I had the same issue and noticed that both the `BINFMT_SCRIPT` and `BINFMT_ELF` options were set to `y`, but I was still having this error.

Please note that the first line of the `init` file `#!/bin/bash` refers to the program which will be used to run the script. In this case, busy box has not compiled bash for us, but rather we only have `/bin/sh`, so the solution is to replace `bash` with `sh` in `init`:

```
#!/bin/sh
```